# Replace some HTML attributes with Jsoup without changing rest of input

Tags: java, html, regex, jsoup

I work with incoming html text blocks, like this:

```
String html = "<p>Some text here with already existing tags and it&#39;s escaped symbols.\n" +
                "    More text here:<br/>\\r\\n---<br/>\\r\\n" +
                "    <img src=\"/attachments/a0d4789a-1575-4b70-b57f-9e8fe21df46b\" sha256=\"2957635fcf46eb54d99f4f335794bd75a89d2ebc1663f5d1708a2fc662ee065c\"></a>" +
                "    It was img tag with attr to replace above</p>\\r\\n\\r\\n<p>More text here\n" +
                "    and here.<br/>\\r\\n---</p>";
```

I need to replace `src` attribute value in `img` tags with slightly modified `sha256` attribute value in the same tag. I can do it easily with Jsoup like this:

```
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        Elements elementsByAttribute = doc.select("img[src]");
        elementsByAttribute.forEach(x -> x.attr("src", "/usr/myfolder/" + x.attr("sha256") + ".zip"));
```

But there is a problem. Incoming text already has some formatting, html tags, escaping etc that need to be preserved. But Jsoup removes tags / adds tags / unescapes / escapes and does some other modifications to the original input.

For example, `System.out.println(doc);` or `System.out.println(doc.html());` gives me following:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <p>Some text here with already existing tags and it's escaped symbols. More text here:<br>\r\n---<br>\r\n <img src="/usr/myfolder/2957635fcf46eb54d99f4f335794bd75a89d2ebc1663f5d1708a2fc662ee065c.zip" sha256="2957635fcf46eb54d99f4f335794bd75a89d2ebc1663f5d1708a2fc662ee065c"> It was img tag with attr to replace above</p>\r\n\r\n
  <p>More text here and here.<br>\r\n---</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

My `src` attribute is replaced, but a lot more html-tags are added, `it&#39;s` is escaped to `it's`.

If I use `System.out.println(doc.text());` i receive following:

```
Some text here with already existing tags and it's escaped symbols. More text here: \r\n--- \r\n It was img tag with attr to replace above\r\n\r\n More text here and here. \r\n---
```

My tags are removed here, `it&#39;s` is escaped to `it's` again.

I tried some other Jsoup features but didn't find how to solve this problem.

Quesion: is there any way to replace only some attributes with Jsoup without changing other tags? Maybe there is some othere library for that purpose? Or my only way is regex?

Comment: Per the [docs](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#parse-java.io.File-java.lang.String-), `.parse()` will produce "sane HTML" so it assumes you wanted to add in the head and body. You may wish to try [`.parseBodyFragment()`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#parseBodyFragment-java.lang.String-). You can also try `doc.body()`

Comment: the same problem remains

Comment: You'll have to dig into the API and figure out whether or not JSOUP is suitable for your needs. JSOUP evidently makes various assumptions so if those assumptions are not good for you then you need to find a different library.

Answer (score 0):

I encoutered same problem and in my case this code doesn't change original formatting.
Try this:

```
public static void m(){

    String html = "<p>Some text here with already existing tags and it&#39;s escaped symbols.\n" +
        "    More text here:<br/>\r\n---<br/>\r\n" +
        "    <img src=\"/attachments/a0d4789a-1575-4b70-b57f-9e8fe21df46b\" sha256=\"2957635fcf46eb54d99f4f335794bd75a89d2ebc1663f5d1708a2fc662ee065c\"></a>" +
        "    It was img tag with attr to replace above</p>\r\n\r\n<p>More text here\n" +
        "    and here.<br/>\r\n---</p>";

    Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(html);
    doc.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false);
    Elements elementsByAttribute = doc.select("img[src]");
    elementsByAttribute.forEach(x -> x.attr("src", "/usr/myfolder/" + x.attr("sha256") + ".zip"));
    String result = doc.body().html();

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

It outputs in console (In your example there is dandling `</a>` after `<img/>` so library remove it):

```
<p>Some text here with already existing tags and it's escaped symbols.
    More text here:<br>
---<br>
    <img src="/usr/myfolder/2957635fcf46eb54d99f4f335794bd75a89d2ebc1663f5d1708a2fc662ee065c.zip" sha256="2957635fcf46eb54d99f4f335794bd75a89d2ebc1663f5d1708a2fc662ee065c">    It was img tag with attr to replace above</p>

<p>More text here
    and here.<br>
---</p>
```

And my case in Kotlin (replace content of `src` of `<img/>` attrs & remove `<script></script>` tags)(`text` is input `String?` variable from outer scope):

```
val content: String get(){
    var c = text ?: ""

    //val document = Jsoup.parse(c)
    val document = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(c)
    document.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false)

    val elementsByAttr = document.select("img[src]")
    elementsByAttr.forEach {
        val srcContent = it.attr("src")
        val (type,value) = srcContent.let {
            val eqIdx = it.indexOf('=')
            it.substring(0, max(0,eqIdx)) to it.substring(eqIdx+1)
        }
        if (type=="path"){
            it.attr("src", ArticleRepo.imgPathPrefix+value)
        }
    }

    document.select("script").remove()

    c = document.body().html()
    return c
}
```